# How to show Data transfer object on a UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, dto, class-diagram, data-transfer-objects

How do I show Data transfer object in a UML class diagram?
So can someone give an example of a UML class diagram with a DTO.

Answer (score 2):

A [data transfer object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) is in principle an object like any other.  As a consequence, you would probably want to represent a DTO class, with all the attributes needed and some operations to convert to and from a data transfer representation (e.g. a data format).

You may have the following additional needs specific to the DTO:

- to highlight that it's a DTO object and avoid confusion with domain objects, you could use an UML profile with a `«DTO»` stereotype that you could show above the class name.
- you could highlight the dependency to the class(es) that the DTO is supposed to transfer.
- If the DTO contains nested objects, you might have to define classes for them as well, with the related associations.
- If a DTO just combines one or several objects of a couple of related classes,  you could as well just show the related objects as attributes of the DTO with their original type, and if needed, with multiplicity.

In some designs however, the DTO object is not really of a different class: it may just be a different representation of the same objects grouped using some special format/encoding (JSON, XML). In this case, from the design perspective it's not necessary, nor even desirable to create distinct classes:  it'd be the same classes, except that the domain objects are  "dehydrated" for storage/transport purpose (i.e.  attributes/state without behaviors, until objects are properly extracted from the DTO) .

Comment: But how do I indicate that a class uses a DTO in a UML class diagram. Which arrow should I use for that?

Comment: @abus above I suggested to use a structural dependency (open arrow head, dashed arrow line) to show that DTO depends on the domain class. This is not to represent a technical dependency, but the fact that if you change the attributes of the domain class, you’ll have to change the dto as well. It could even be a usage dependency, if the dto has a constructor or some operations to add some domain object. You can easily follow the arrow back to find for a class the corresponding dto(s). Now, it all depends of your design. If it’s up to the class to create its dto, the dependency would be reverted

Comment: However this design couples the dto and the domain object and make this an inflexible design. This is why the DTO pattern (see hyperlink in my answer) uses an intermediate class with the responsibility to take domain objects and aggregate them into a dto. This is a proven robust design, and you just have to follow the dotted lines for finding out the relationships.